# Adding another row with data

Tags: vba, excel

I've looked hight and low for a correct method, but I'm having so much trouble.

I'm trying to add another row with data on the end of my table, but all it keeps doing is adding another row but doesn't add the actual data.

```
Sub CommandButton1_Click()
Dim lastRow As Long
Dim iHeader As Integer
Dim strData As String
strname = InputBox(prompt:="Enter data")
    Set myTable = ActiveSheet.ListObjects("Table1")
    ActiveSheet.ListObjects("Table1").ListRows.Add
         With ActiveSheet.ListObjects("Table1")
            lastRow = ActiveSheet.ListObjects("Table1").ListRows.Count
        End With
    ActiveSheet.Cells(lastRow, "M").Value = strData    
End Sub
```

It will only add a row to the table but it will not add the strData value no matter what I try. The Column its using for testing purposes is "M"

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: I tried deleting the extra +1's but still having the same issue where it keeps adding the row but not the data in the row

Comment: My table does start in row 1. I added `MsgBox lastRow` Its giving me the correct row number when the code is executed but still no data.

Comment: Haha just noticed the typo.  Your variable is strData but you use strname in the InputBox code line...

Comment: Gotta use that `Option Explicit` bro!

Comment: haha, I just realized that myself! .... I do apologize, been a long day

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like a typographical error: (Which is why you should always use [`Option Explicit`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y9341s4f.aspx))

```
Option Explicit
Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    Dim lastRow As Long
    Dim iHeader As Integer
    Dim strData As String
    strData = InputBox(prompt:="Enter data") 'Fixed variable here
    Set myTable = ActiveSheet.ListObjects("Table1")
    With myTable
        .ListRows.Add
        lastRow = .ListRows.Count
    End With
    ActiveSheet.Cells(lastRow, "M").Value = strData    
End Sub
```